# Raise event when any of class method called

Tags: c#, asp.net, cloud

I need to log calls for class methods, in my custom logger. In case I have WebService class (.asmx) I can subscribe logging method to event `Application_BeginRequest` and log every call to web method of this web service. But I have only simple class with attribute `[ServiceInfo]`. And when someone calls it's methods - `Application_BeginRequest` doesn't fire. I can call logging method in all class methods, but I think it's not correct. So, is there any ways to catch event when someone calls any of method in such class? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use AOP to do that. A simple approach would be to inherit from ContextBoundObject, check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8414/The-simplest-AOP-scenario-in-C) article for detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to implement a mechanism that logs when a particular method was called in your class. Although you could add this the call into each method as you mentioned this isn't 100% correct and there is a better way of doing this by implementing AOP.

Logging is a classic example of a [cross cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) which AOP addresses.

I've previously used Microsoft Unity for Interception (see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx)), this will allow you to decorate a class method that you wish to intercept (i.e. log information about) perhaps by decorating it with an attribute.

e.g.

```
[Log]
public MyMethodToLog(string x, int y)
{
   //Class Implementation
}
```

The beauty of this is that you have no calls to the logging method in your class implementation and you can remove the logging by simply removing the attribute, or, configuring your logging code to only perform logging under certain conditions (e.g. when a configuration value is set)